# Access: Combine entries with duplicate fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

My database looks like this

Data:

```
ID | Number | A | Version
1  |  N123  | K |    1
2  |  N123  | O |    1
3  |  N123  | O |    2
4  |  N123  | K |    2
5  |  N234  | K |    1
6  |  N234  | O |    1
7  |  N456  | K |    1
8  |  N456  | L |    1
9  |  N456  | K |    2
10 |  N456  | L |    2
```

My result should look like this:

```
Number |  A   | Version
N123   | O, K |    2
N234   | O, K |    1
N456   | K, L |    2
```

That means I have a table with duplicate entries relating to number (and version). e.g: N123 exists twice in version 1. Once with A=K and once with A=O. Combined I have N123 (V1) with K=A and O. This bundle has a duplicate in Version 2.
What I want to query is die highest Version and a combination of K so that I have no duplicate entries anymore.

Data by the way is a result of a query from a bigger data source. Maybe the solution can be within this initial query:

```
SELECT Data.[Number], Data.[Version], Data.[K]
FROM Data
WHERE (((Data.[Number]) In (SELECT [Number] FROM [Data] As Tmp GROUP BY [Number],[Version] HAVING Count(*)>1  And [Version] = [Data].[Version])))
ORDER BY Data.[Number], Data.[Version];
```

Comment: mysql or access?

Comment: Just access - sorry for the irritation

Comment: MS Access does not have `group_concat()` or anything similar.  This is very hard in that database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I said in my comment that for OleDb purposes there is no solution, I was assuming that [A] contained an unknown (and limitless) number of possibilities.  However, if [A] is effectively an enumeration, you can achieve concatenation in MS Access using SQL without the help of a self-written function.  You can do this with a sequence of LEFT JOINS:

```
SELECT Number, ConcatKLO, MAX(version) AS MaxVersion FROM
(SELECT number, version, left(ConcatA,Len(ConcatA) -2) as ConcatKLO FROM
(SELECT d.number, d.version, IIF(k.A IS NULL, "",k.A + ", ")  + IIF(l.A IS NULL, "",l.A + ", ")  + IIF(o.A IS NULL, "",o.A + ", ") AS ConcatA FROM
(((SELECT DISTINCT number, version FROM Data) as d
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT number, A, version FROM Data WHERE A = 'K') as k
ON d.number = k.number and d.version = k.version)
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT number, A, version FROM Data WHERE A = 'O') as o
ON d.number = o.number and d.version = o.version)
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT number, A, version FROM Data WHERE A = 'L') as l
ON d.number = l.number and d.version = l.version) as c) as a
GROUP BY Number, concatklo
```

The problem with a call from OleDB, is that you can only use functions built into the Access engine.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `GROUP_CONCAT` and `CONCAT` functions along with `MAX` and a `GROUP BY` to achieve this.

```
SELECT Number, 
GROUP_CONCAT(A) AS A,
MAX(Version) AS Version
FROM data
WHERE CONCAT(Version,'-',Number) IN (SELECT CONCAT(MAX(Version),'-',Number) FROM data GROUP BY Number)
GROUP BY Number
ORDER BY Number
```

Output

```
Number  A    Version
N123    O,K  2
N234    K,O  1
N456    K,L  2
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c556b6/40/0

Comment: There is no group_concat() in access

Comment: You tagged your question as MySQL

Comment: Not only MySql - MS-Access also. Sorry for that! I thought this was familiar

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "Not only MySQL"?

Comment: I tagged it with Mysql AND access - not only with mysql. Sorry for the irritation. I need a solution in ms-access

Comment: Yes i know that, i am asking if it is an MS Access solution with a MySQL database also?

Comment: If you are using this only within access then you can use Allen Browne's http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html  ConcatRelated function.  If you are needing this externally (e.g. through OleDb), then there is no solution.  What I do in the latter case, is to do the concatenation myself on the c# side.